# Let $A\subseteq \Bbb R^n$, then $(\overline{A^c})^c=\mathring A$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Let $A\subseteq \Bbb R^n$, then:

$A^{c\bar{}c}=\mathring A$

Notation: As an example $(\bar{A^c})^c=A^{c\bar{}c}$

Dem:

We know that $A\subseteq \bar A$, now if we take the complement on both sides: $A^{\bar{}c}\subseteq A^c$

Now, knowing that $A^{\bar{}c}$ is an open set, then  $A^{\bar{}c}\subseteq \bar A$
$$\implies A^{coc}\subset A^{\bar{}cc}=\bar A$$

Now, $\color{blue}{A^{co}\subseteq A^c}$, then:
$$\implies A=A^{cc}\subseteq A^{coc}$$
$$\implies \color{blue}{\bar A\subseteq A^{coc}}$$

Therefore, $A^{coc}=\bar A$

Can you explain me what exactly happened to get to the parts in $\color{blue}{blue}$, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the parts in blue:

- The statement $A^{{\complement}~\bigcirc}\subseteq A^\complement$ follows from the fact that $E^\bigcirc\subseteq E$ for any set $E$.
- The assertion $\bar A\subseteq A^{\complement~\bigcirc~\complement}$ follows from taking the closure of both sides of the prior equality $A\subseteq A^{\complement~\bigcirc~\complement}$ and noting that $\overline{A^{\complement~\bigcirc~\complement}}=A^{\complement~\bigcirc~\complement}$ since $A^{\complement~\bigcirc~\complement}$ is a closed set. $A^{\complement~\bigcirc~\complement}$ is a closet set because it is the complement of the set $A^{\complement~\bigcirc}$, which is open.